# Chrome and HTML5 offline storage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, blob, offline-storage

I am working on chrome extension that should store blobs (unlimited size) to browser storage. For that I am using 
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota and 
 window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT,...). 
Results are not reliable,  navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota  is invoking success callback in majority of  cases but sometimes without any error it is not being invoked.

Is this known problem, any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser. Try storing them as strings in chrome.storage.local or IndexedDB.

Comment: This is a video blob that can grow up to couple of gigs. Local or indexdb is for strings.